# Product Page is Blank pointing to non existant template frontend/base/default/template/page/column.phtml

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, template, layout

I am going a little mad trying to figure out why the product page for my site is pointing to frontend/base/default/template/page/column.phtml which does not exist.  Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by 'blank'. No header, footer, nothing?
Anyhow, this is true, no such template file should be in `base/default` and if this is true, it is perfectly normal to get blank page. 
I think the question you need to ask is: **Where is this template defined to be your product page template?**
I can't be sure, but most likely you have a file called `local.xml` in your `app\design\frontend\PACKAGENAME\THEMENAME\layout\` folder.
 In there search for the template name `column.phtml` I think what you want, is to have `1column` layout. Then you just have small typo. You need to have '1' in front of 'column'. Correct would be following:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

p.s. [Here is a nice module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magneto-debug-8676.html) for debug'ing magento ;)

Comment: Yup, problem was a missing template file.  Replaced column.phtml wtih 1column.phtml in catalog.xml.